# Хорошая книга для начала (MS Visual C++)

Tags: c++, книги

Хорошая ли книга "С/C++ и MS Visual C++ 2010 для начинающих (Борис Пахомов)"? Если нет, то подскажите, пожалуйста, книгу для самообучения, чтобы было понятно **новичку.** Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и другая литература по С++](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1)

Answer (score 1):

Не скажу за всю Одессу. Но я прошел через эти книги:

- [В. В. Подбельский Язык Си++](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/3223525/)
- [Николас А. Солтер, Скотт Дж. Клепер C++ для профессионалов](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/2847443/)

Про Страуструпа писать не буду=)

На мой взгляд. для требуемых знаний в универе вполне хватило Подбельского. Еще кто-то из "ленивых" читал что-то под названием С++ за 21 день, говорили, что тоже неплохо.

Comment: Слишком полный, слишком дотошный, как мне тогда показалось. На мой взгляд, если и читать, то не первой книгой. Не для "быстрого" старта. Все имхо конечно=) Прошло 4 дня - как успехи?

Comment: Немножко уже прочитал, но смотрю еще книги (их целая куча)

Comment: Я хотел бы узнать вы профессиональный программист? Если да, то скажите помогли ли книги которые вы мне посоветовали? Я имею ввиду после их прочтения смогли ли вы писать какие-нибудь полезные программы(спрашиваю, потому что уже долго ищу книги и хотелось бы остановиться)

Comment: Дипломированный специалист на пути к профессионализму=) Помогли. И в общем понимании вопроса и конкретно по данному языку. Пишу на c# в данный момент. Вы же понимаете, что только прочтение книг не добавит вам прикладного опыта написания "полезных программ". На вашем месте я бы остановился на любой более-менее понравившейся книге и начал писать по примерам/заданиям, которых в интернете предостаточно. Если есть еще какие-нибудь вопросы - стучитесь 19464696

Comment: Спасибо остановлюсь на книгах, которые вы посоветовали.

Answer (score 1):

Р. Лафоре - Объектно-ориентированное программирование в С++

Comment: Лафоре - пожалуй одна из наиболее понятных и простых в освоении.

Answer (score 0):

Освой самостоятельно C++ за 21 день Автор: Либерти Д.